Find direct children after tag "get_by_test_id"
I'm using playwright for testing web pages. When I use id tag as locator, I can find direct children of tagged div:
page.locator('#id_tag > div').all()

Now I try to use test_id tag and I need to find direct children:
page.get_by_test_id("test_id_tag").locator("div").all()

But this is equivalent to:
locator('#test_id_tag >> div').all()

So Playwright returns direct children, but also sub-children, sub-sub-children, etc.
Minimal example:
html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div  id="id_tag" >
    <div >level_1
        <div >level_1_1
            <i>i1_1_1</i>
            <i>i1_1_2</i>
            <i>i1_1_3</i>
        </div>
        <div >level_1_2
            <div>level_1_2_1
            <i >level_1_2_1_1</i>
            </div>
            <i > level_1_2_2</i>
            <span >level_1_2_3 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div >level_2
        <div >level_2_1
            <i>i2_1_1</i>
            <i>i2_1_2</i>
            <i>i2_1_3</i>
        </div>
        <div >level_2_2
            <div>level_2_2_1
            <i >level_2_2_1_1</i>
            </div>
            <i > level_2_2_2</i>
            <span >level_2_2_3 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div >level_3
        <div >level_3_1
            <i>i3_1_1</i>
            <i>i3_1_2</i>
            <i>i3_1_3</i>
        </div>
        <div >level_3_2
            <div>level_3_2_1
            <i >level_3_2_1_1</i>
            </div>
            <i > level_3_2_2</i>
            <span >level_3_2_3 </span>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>

Python code with "id" attribute and expected result:
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(html)
    divs = page.locator('#id_tag > div').all()
    for el in divs:
        inner_txt = el.locator(div).inner_text()
        print(f'{inner_txt=}')
        # =>  expected result
        #     level_1
        #     level_2
        #     level 3
    browser.close()

Is there any way to find only direct child elements using get_by_test_id("test_id_tag")?

What is attribute name of testid? Do you use a custom attribute or data-testid ? If you use a different attribute you have to set the name in your code. Please share the node. Please avoid using >> or > in locators. When the DOM changes, your chain can break as well. Prefer chaining locators, e.g. locator('#id_tag').locator('div').all()

I use data-testid attribute
   <div> ... </div>   
   <div> ... </div>    
</div>


In case I use chaining locators, e.g.
locator('#id_tag').locator('div').all() i got direct children also sub-children, sub-sub-children etc, and it isn't what I need.    I need list of direct childrens only, to manipulate them further on.

please show the node of your children. You should update your question to not to flood the comments.

Best practice is not to use CSS at all in Playwright tests. Please share a [mcve] with context to avoid an xy problem. Show the behavior/page you want to test and your current full test attempt. .all() is an antipattern, it doesn't wait. Avoid element handles. locator("div") is too broad and, not user-visible. All that said, page.get_by_test_id("test_id_tag").locator("> *").all() might work.

Hi, all, appreciate your support . Sorry to say, neither locator   page.get_by_test_id("test_id_tag").locator("> div").all() nor locator  page.get_by_test_id("test_id_tag").locator(":scope > div").all()  does work for me.
By this way  collects childrens, sub-childrens, sub-sub-children divs.

I don't suggest doing this in tests, but you can get all immediate children with .locator("> *") or .locator(":scope > *"). Replace * with div if you only want div children.
If you then want to extract the text content from that node, ignoring the recursive text content, you can use JS in an evaluate to find all child text nodes.
Minimal example:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright  # 1.44.0


html = """
<div id="id_tag">
  <div>
    a
    <div>
      ignore
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    b
    <div>
      ignore
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    c
    <div>
      ignore
    </div>
    c
  </div>
</div>"""


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(html)
    top_level_text = (
        page.locator("#id_tag")
        .locator("> *")
        .evaluate_all("""els =>
          els.map(el =>
            [...el.childNodes]
              .filter(el => el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
              .map(el => el.textContent.trim())
              .join("")
          );
        """)
    )
    print(top_level_text)  # => ['a', 'b', 'cc']
    browser.close()

If you can guarantee that your target text nodes are always the first child, as in your example, you can simplify the JS to
els
  .filter(el => el.childNodes[0]?.textContent.trim())
  .map(el => el.childNodes[0].textContent.trim())

Taking a step back, intensive JS and CSS like this should generally be avoided in tests. Prefer user-visible locators. Alternatively, perhaps a snapshot test on these nodes is appropriate.
Avoid .all() and element handles--they don't auto-wait and can't be used in web-first assertions at the time of writing. Unfortunately, my code doesn't auto-wait, either, which is one disadvantage to the heavy JS approach.
Note also that <div  id="id_tag" > doesn't have a test id--that'd have to be <div data-testid="test_id_tag"> for get_by_test_id("test_id_tag") to find the element (although you can override the default test id, I don't recommend it, and certainly not to set it to id=).
